# Rows getting deleted through Excel VBA code but shapes not re-aligning

Tags: excel, vba, alignment, rows, shapes

```
 gwbkEach.Worksheets(6).Range(rngDeleteStart, rngDeleteEnd.Offset(-1)).EntireRow.Delete
```

The above code deletes row 11-54($11:$54). But the shapes which lies beyond Row-54 does not shift upwards. All shapes has the `placement` property set to `xlMoveAndSize`.

- When I manually delete the rows the shapes re-position themselves
  accordingly as expected.
- Strangely, when I put a break-point in the above line of code then
  everything works fine and the shapes re-position themselves as
  expected.

I tried to use `DoEvents` , `Application.Wait` around the above line of code, but nothing seems to work. Please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed when I added a code to activate the sheet:

```
gwbkEach.Worksheets(6).Activate    ' FIXED THE ISSUE
gwbkEach.Worksheets(6).Range(rngDeleteStart, rngDeleteEnd.Offset(-1)).EntireRow.Delete
```

NOTE: You have to **avoid** using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in order for the above solution to work